# Logarithm of a negative number

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

We know this identity: $\ln(\frac{a}{b}) = \ln(a) - \ln(b)$

Suppose both $a$ and $b$ are negative. Then the left-hand size evaluates to something, it is a logarithm of a positive number (minus signs cancel); and the right-hand size is undefined—you take 'log' of negative numbers.

What's wrong with it?

Comment: Nothing. You dropped the condition "whenever $a,b>0$" from the full steatement of the identity.

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen: It's also true whenever $a,b<0$ (see my answer below). In fact, it is probably true for every $a,b \neq 0$ as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This identity holds only and only if **both** $a$ and $b$ are strictly positive: $$\ln\left(\dfrac ab\right)=\ln(a)-\ln(b).$$
For its proof: Let $a=c^x$ and $b=c^y$, and so $\color{red}{\underline{\color{black}{a,b>0}}}$ and: $$\dfrac ab=\dfrac {c^x}{c^y}=c^{x-y}\Rightarrow \log_c\left({\dfrac ab}\right)=\log_c(c^{x-y})=x-y=\log_c a-\log_c b.$$

Comment: The identity also holds if $a,b<0$, and in fact, it probably holds for every $a,b \neq 0$!!!

Comment: @barakmanos Logarithms are not defined for negative numbers over the reals;

Comment: The logarithm of a negative real number is a complex number (hence well defined).

Comment: @barakmanos But we're dealing with real numbers here. (see the tag)

Comment: Sorry, I don't see any *real-numbers* tag on this question.

Comment: @barakmanos It's [tag:algebra-precalculus].

Answer (score 2):

$ln(x)=ln((-x)(-1))=ln(-x)+ln(-1)=ln(-x)+\pi i$

Having said that, let's consider the expression $ln(a)-ln(b)$:

$ln(a)-ln(b) = ln(-a)+\pi i-ln(-b)-\pi i=ln(-a)-ln(-b)=ln(\frac{-a}{-b})=ln(\frac{a}{b})$

Bottom line, the logarithm of a negative real number is a complex number (hence well defined).

Update: in contrast with some of the responses to your post, this identity is true for **every** $a,b \neq 0$.

Comment: This answer is actually more valuable!

Comment: @werediver: thank you!

Comment: More simply, it holds by $\log(-1)-\log(-1)=0$. Negative logarithm is multivalue, not $\log(-1)≠\pi i$.

Comment: @TakahiroWaki: So I guess that [the answer in Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=ln(-1)&rct=j) is wrong too then, is that right?

Comment: @barakmanos Off course, since $\log(-1)$ is not unique. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1019177/how-is-ln-1-i-pi

Comment: @TakahiroWaki: Of course - the answer in Google is wrong?