# What's wrong with this logarithm calculation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

We know that $\displaystyle\log_a(xy)=\log_ax+\log_ay$.

Consider the following:

> $$\displaystyle\ln(1)=\displaystyle\ln((-1)\times(-1))=\displaystyle\ln(-1)+\displaystyle\ln(-1)
> $$

$\displaystyle\ln(1) $ is a completely valid statement, but I'm not sure if $\displaystyle\ln(-1)+\displaystyle\ln(-1) $ is.

$\displaystyle\ln(-1) $ doesn't exist, but $\displaystyle\ln((-1)\times(-1)) $ does, and if I plug $\displaystyle\ln((-1)\times(-1)) $ into my calculator it gives a 0 as the answer (which is correct), but if I plug in $\displaystyle\ln(-1)+\displaystyle\ln(-1) $ it says that there is a domain error (which there is). So my question is, what is wrong with the highlighted equation?

Comment: $\log_a(xy)=\log_a(x)+\log_a(y)$ is only true when $x,y>0$, I think.

Comment: I also think that $\ln (-1)= \pi i$, but I don't know enough math to know if this is true.

Comment: If you google "ln(-1)" it says that it's equal to 3.14159265i, so I'd say you're right. I didn't know about this, cool! EDIT: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1019177/how-is-ln-1-i-pi

Comment: This was Bernoulli’s argument for $\log(-x)=\log x$, which caused a long debate until Euler, who initially agreed with Bernoulli, found the right approach to complex exponentials.

Comment: @egreg Since you appear to more well-versed in mathematics, can you tell me something that I have been wondering: Is $e^{\pi i}+1=0$ a definition or a Theorem? I would normally post this as a seperate question, but I am pretty sure that it has been asked before, and I think that some people could find this offensive.

Comment: @MXYMXY It's an identity, which I think differs from a definition or a theorem.

Comment: @MXYMXY It mostly depends on how you introduce the complex exponential. If you define $e^z=\sum_{n\ge0}z^n/n!$, the relation $e^{\pi i}+1=0$ can be deduced. If you define $e^{x+yi}=e^x(\cos y+i\sin y)$, then $e^{\pi i}+1=0$ by definition.

Comment: I'd call it an identity because the Wikipedia says its an identity:  Euler's identity.  Somewhat vague though.

Comment: @SimpleArt: true, but "identity" just means a statement that two things are equal (identical, hence identity). The identity can still be either a definition or a theorem (or neither), so calling it an identity doesn't get us off the hook of deciding whether or not it's a theorem :-)

Comment: The notation $\ln x$ is reserved for positive real $x$. There are complex logarithms. For them, $\log$ is used

Comment: @user254665: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm) says $\ln$ is also fine for complex values?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> $$\displaystyle\log_a(xy)=\log_ax+\log_ay$$

The above identity holds only for $x,y>0$ and $a\not =1$, $a>0$.

Comment: Alright, well that settles it!

Comment: @user265554 Yup you are right.

Answer (score 10):

It is sort of true if we allow complex numbers to come in:

$$\log_a(1)=\frac{\ln(1)}{\ln(a)}=\frac{\pm2\pi ik}{\ln(a)}$$

$$\log_a(-1)=\frac{\ln(-1)}{\ln(a)}=\frac{\pm\pi i(2k-1)}{\ln(a)}$$

$$k=0,1,2,3,\dots$$

So it is sort of true that $\log(1)=2\log(-1)$, but this just depends on what is allowed.

$$2\log_a(-1)=\frac{\pm\pi i(4k-2)}{\ln(a)}$$

We are trying to make the two equal, so we must have:

$$2k=4n-2,n=0,1,2,3,\dots$$

We use $n$ at this stage because $\log_a(1)$ and $\log_a(-1)$ don't have to rely on the same constant, it could just as easily be $k=1$ and $n=1$ or $k=3$ and $n=2$.

In fact, now there are an infinite amount of solutions, many of which match up together.

However, all of the solutions to $2\log_a(-1)$ do not match up with all of the solutions in $\log_a(1)$, actually, it only matches up with half of the solutions.

So, like I said, it just depends on how you look at it.

Comment: @RaymondManzoni Oh, yes, my bad.

Answer (score -1):

Basically, once you go to taking the log of negative numbers, and therefore getting complex results, you are into the realm of multi-valued functions. Cf. $arcsin(\theta)$ etc.
Euler's identity says $exp(i\pi) = -1$ But also, for example, $exp(-i\pi) = -1$. So by taking logs of both sides, we get $log(-1) = (2n - 1)i\pi$ for an arbitrary integer value of n, and it is effectively by convention that we take $n = 0$ to get the principal value of the log function..

Then the effect of writing $log(1) = log(-1) + log(-1)$ simply amounts to:
$$0 = (2m - 1)i\pi + (2n - 1)i\pi$$which reduces to choosing m, n such that $m + n = 1$.

This is the same order of paradox as saying $\sqrt4 = 2$ and $\sqrt4 = -2$. By convention we take the principal (positive) value throughout; but there are circumstances where we have to break the convention to get a sensible result.